# Py4j Java Error: An error occurred while calling o801.get

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using udf to convert a sparse vector to a dense vector.The functions i am using are udf, Vectors, VectorUDT.The java version is jdk8 and the spark is 3.3.1 .
I have done Vector Assembly to convert features to Numerical_Features.
The piece of code i am using is :

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
sparseToDense = udf(lambda v : Vectors.dense(v), VectorUDT())
densefeatureDF = df8.withColumn('features_array', sparseToDense('Numeric_Features'))
densefeatureDF.select("Numeric_Features", "features_array").show(5, False)
```

I am getting the following error . This is a sparksql problem Can you help me with the problem ?

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-4ab73927e6bf> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors, VectorUDT
----> 2 sparseToDense = udf(lambda v : Vectors.dense(v), VectorUDT())
      3 densefeatureDF = df8.withColumn('features_array', sparseToDense('Numeric_Features'))
      4 densefeatureDF.select("Numeric_Features", "features_array").show(5, False)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    158             return getattr(functions, f.__name__)(*args, **kwargs)
    159         else:
--> 160             return f(*args, **kwargs)
    161 
    162     return cast(FuncT, wrapped)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/functions.py in udf(f, returnType)
  10212         )
  10213     else:
> 10214         return _create_py_udf(f=f, returnType=returnType, evalType=PythonEvalType.SQL_BATCHED_UDF)
  10215 
  10216 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/udf.py in _create_py_udf(f, returnType, evalType)
    120     is_arrow_enabled = (
    121         session is not None
--> 122         and session.conf.get("spark.sql.execution.pythonUDF.arrow.enabled") == "true"
    123     )
    124 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/sql/conf.py in get(self, key, default)
     59         self._checkType(key, "key")
     60         if default is _NoValue:
---> 61             return self._jconf.get(key)
     62         else:
     63             if default is not None:
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1320 
   1321         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1322         return_value = get_return_value(
   1323             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1324 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pyspark/errors/exceptions/captured.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    167     def deco(*a: Any, **kw: Any) -> Any:
    168         try:
--> 169             return f(*a, **kw)
    170         except Py4JJavaError as e:
    171             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o801.get.
: java.util.NoSuchElementException: spark.sql.execution.pythonUDF.arrow.enabled
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.noSuchElementExceptionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:1678)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.$anonfun$getConfString$3(SQLConf.scala:4568)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.internal.SQLConf.getConfString(SQLConf.scala:4568)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.RuntimeConfig.get(RuntimeConfig.scala:72)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.